# Take input in the view and pass it to the contoller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code in not rendering even the buttons:

```
<% form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
<%=text_field_tag :my_input%>
<%=submit_tag "Send input"%>
<%end%>
```

the controller create_new has the following method:

```
def input
@my_input=params[:my_input]
end
```

the routes.rb has::

```
resources :create_new do
   post :input, :on=>:collection
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%= form_tag` instead of `<% form_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3 we have to use '=' symbol for form_tag and form_for. so change your code as follows..

```
 <%=form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
 <%=text_field_tag :my_input%>
 <%=submit_tag "Send input"%>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag input_create_new_path, :html_options => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :my_input%>
  <%= f.submit "Send input"%>
<%end%>
```