# I want to take input in the view and pass it to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code in not rendering even the buttons:

```
<% form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
  <%=text_field_tag :my_input%> 
  <%=submit_tag "Send input"%>
<%end%>
```

the controller create_new has the following method

```
def input 
  @my_input=params[:my_input] 
end
```

the routes.rb has:

```
resources :create_new do post :input, :on=>:collection
```

Comment: You ask the same question again, have you tried answer given in your first question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580862/take-input-in-the-view-and-pass-it-to-the-contoller

Comment: You have asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580862/take-input-in-the-view-and-pass-it-to-the-contoller

Answer (score 0):

The `=` was missing.

```
<%= form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :my_input%>
  <%=submit_tag "Send input"%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
```

It has a missing = , check this

```
<%= form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the form tag is a helper it actually needs to be displayed in the view.  the <% just allows code to run, does not actually display the result of the code.

Try using

```
<%= form_tag :controller=> :create_new, :action=>:input do %>
```

this includes the = which will actually display the result of the code run.

Hope that helps.